# I'm trying to json_encode an array to a string to set it as a html data attribute but its outputting &quot; instead of speech marks

Tags: php, json, wordpress, encoding

As the title states, I am trying to pass JSON data from PHP to a HTML data-attribute within a WordPress environment but the rendered data is being outputted with HTML entities " instead of speech marks.

Note: this previously worked

the function:

```
function build_ga_tracking($category, $label, $action = 'click', $value = '', $event = 'event') {
  $tracking = array(
    'event' => $event,
    'category' => $category,
    'label' => $label,
    'action' => $action,
    'value' => $value
  );

  $jsonEncodedTracking = json_encode($tracking);

  return "data-tracking='".$jsonEncodedTracking."'";
}

echo("<li><a href='" . $item->url . "' " . build_ga_tracking('Primary Menu', $cleanTitle, 'Click-'.$cleanTitle) . ">" . $title . "</a></li>");
```

which outputs as:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8080/category/money-tips/" data-tracking="{&quot;event&quot;:&quot;event&quot;,&quot;category&quot;:&quot;Primary Menu&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Money Tips&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;Click-Money Tips&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;}">Money Tips</a></li>
```

note:

```
echo(build_ga_tracking('Primary Menu', $cleanTitle, 'Click-'.$cleanTitle));
```

outputs correctly:

```
data-tracking='{"event":"event","category":"Primary Menu","label":"Money Tips","action":"Click-Money Tips","value":""}'
```

I've tried using `esc_attr()` `esc_js()` and `wp_json_encode()` with no luck.

Comment: What is this `roostermoney_build_ga_tracking`? Should that be `build_ga_tracking`?

Comment: @disinfor, sorry that was a typo and not the issue. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This was purely a rendering issue with Chrome dev tools. When inspecting the source code, it's outputting correctly.

2 days of debugging and a massive face palm later.